# C# serialize and deserialize json to txt file

Tags: c#, json, wpf, list, json.net

I'm using [NewtonSoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for handling json in my wpf application. I've got a customer that can be saved to a txt file (no database involved). I'm doing that like this:

```
public int store(string[] reservation)
{
    JObject customer = new JObject(
        new JProperty("id", this.getNewId()),
        new JProperty("name", reservation[0]),
        new JProperty("address", reservation[1]),
        new JProperty("gender", reservation[2]),
        new JProperty("age", reservation[3])
    );

    using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(Settings.databasePath +  "customer.json"))
    using (JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(file))
    {
        customer.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Lars","address":"Bosch 10","gender":"Man","age":"19"}
```

Then I'm trying to get all customers like this:

```
if(File.Exists(Settings.databasePath + "customer.json"))
{
    List<Customer> customers;

    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Settings.databasePath + "customer.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(json);
    }
}
```

But I receive this error (can't copy the error):

[image] Already tried to store it like a jArray but that's not working. How do I get this to work?

Any help is going to be appreciated. :)

Comment: Well you only wrote a single customer to the file but try to read an array of customers...that can't work. _Why_ did writing a JArray of customers not work? This is what you need to do.

Comment: Are you intending to save multiple customers in the same file? Or mutliple files in same location for each customer?

Comment: Off topic: gender should be male/female

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to save multiple customers to the same file. I will post an edit why JArray did not work. One moment.

Comment: Is your customers really has name property inside it?

Comment: Yes, I've checked that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do it like follows:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public void AddCustomer(Customer newCustomer)
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(pathToTheFile);
    var customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(json);
    customers.Add(newCustomer);
    File.WriteAllText(pathToTheFile, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers));
}

public Customer GetCustomer(string id)
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(pathToTheFile);
    var customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(json);
    var result = new Customer();
    foreach (var c in customers)
    {
        if (c.Id == id)
        {
            result = c;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This approach means unnecessary saving of temporary string representation into memory. I would prefer dealing with streams instead.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you try to get a **List of Customer** from your file while you are saving **only one** customer.

If you want store multiple customers in your file you have to create a **JArray** and add your customer into it :

```
//The customers array
private JArray customers = new JArray();

//Store new customer in array
public int Store(string[] reservation)
{
    JObject customer = new JObject(
        new JProperty("id", this.getNewId()),
        new JProperty("name", reservation[0]),
        new JProperty("address", reservation[1]),
        new JProperty("gender", reservation[2]),
        new JProperty("age", reservation[3])
    );

    //Add customer to customers array
    customers.add(customer);

    return 1;
}
```

Then, just save the JArray of customer :

```
//Save array
public void Save()
{

    StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(Settings.databasePath +  "customer.json");

    using (JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(file))
    {
        //Save JArray of customers
        customers.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

You'll probably have to adapt this code to your own needs.

I try my best to write correct english, but be free to correct me.