# How can I persist data-objects in a datagrid without using a database

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I need to create a `Datagrid` that will show a list of cars, I want to be able to add, delete and save new ones but I don't have access to a database.

What would be my best options?

Is it possible to save objects in a text file?

### Car Object

```
namespace DataGridTesting
{
    public class Car
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public bool HasSunRoof { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Codebehind

```
namespace DataGridTesting
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            carsDataGrid.ItemsSource = LoadCollectionData();
        }

        private List<Car> LoadCollectionData()
        {
            List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
            cars.Add(new Car() {
                ID = 101,
                Model = "Mustang",
                Make = "Ford",
                Year = "1995"
                HasSunRoof = false
            });

            cars.Add(new Car() {
                ID = 102,
                Model = "Mazda3",
                Make = "Mazda",
                Year = "2011"
                HasSunRoof = false
            });

            cars.Add(new Car() {
                ID = 103,
                Model = "F150",
                Make = "Ford",
                Year = "2018"
                HasSunRoof = false
            });

            return cars;
        }
    }
}
```

### XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTesting.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridTesting"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="604.138">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="carsDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="240" Width="576"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why do you not have access to a database?

Comment: I don’t have access to a server.

Comment: Can you install sql express or sqlite?  There are many different types of sql databases that dont require a standalone 'server'.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I’m in a restricted network.

Comment: Of course you can serialize the objects to JSON or XML and save to a text file.

Comment: If you can write to a file you can use sqlite.

Comment: @kennyzx  - what’s easier to work with, XML or JSON?

Comment: JSON. Use NewtonSoft library, basically it takes just one line.

Comment: @Neil  - Do you need to install Sqlite in order to use it or is just a matter of creating a file with the .sqlite extension?

Comment: Sqlite is just a nuget package and it will create a local file.

Comment: @kennyzx  I will take a look at NewtonSoft.

Comment: @Neil - ah, cool that makes it easy. What would you consider easier, JSON or Sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the options we provided in comments.

Probably the easiest way to persist objects is by serializing them to JSON (a string) then save to a text file. By using [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library, it is as easy as

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cars);
File.WriteAllText(file, data);
```

Later you can use the DeserializeObject method to re-construct the objects from the saved string.

Another format for serialization is XML. It is as easy as JSON but the output string is more verbose thus less readable.

.NET has built-in support for XML serialization so you don’t need third party libraries. The same might be true for JSON, but NewtonSoft is used by everyone for JSON serialization.

If you are comfortable with SQL, you can try SQLite which is a file-based database (by convention it has a  .sqlite file extension) and doesn’t require a stand-alone server. You need to reference SQLite.NET library in you program, and its connection string is like

```
“Data Source=mydb.sqlite;Version=3;”
```

then you can use it like other full-fledged databases.

Comment: Ref link for reading and using the DeserializeObject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427643/c-sharp-serialize-and-deserialize-json-to-txt-file